# if...else statement in Tornado

Tags: if-statement, tornado

I have two variables 'usrpermnet' and 'usrpermdev' that can have length of 0 or not. I want compare those length. I wrote this in tornado

```
if len(usrpermdev) > 0
    usrperm = usrpermdev
else
    usrperm = usrpermnet
```

but I have an error.

Which is the way in that I have to write? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the colons:

```
if len(usrpermdev) > 0:
    usrperm = usrpermdev
else:
    usrperm = usrpermnet
```

This has nothing to do with Tornado; it's basic Python. You might want to have a look at the [Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/).

Answer (score 3):

Try using this:-

```
  {% if len(usrpermdev) > 0 %}
     usrperm = usrpermdev
  {% else %}
      usrperm = usrpermnet
  {% end %}
```

Comment: You can use the HTML code where I have used:- usrperm = usrpermdev or usrperm = usrpermnet

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work. In the python script I can't write in this way. I can write something like I write in the question, but of course in an other way...